# Reading a .txt file until it finds a certain word or reading a certain amount of lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was just wondering if it is possible to read a .txt file until you find a certain word or reading a certain amount of lines. I'm using the Java Scanner and this is what I tried.

```
    reader = new Scanner(new File(path));

    find = (String) wupList.getSelectedItem();

    reader.useDelimiter(find);

    while(reader.hasNext()){

        website = reader.next();
        username = reader.next();
        password = reader.next();

    }
```

This is just a little program I'm making to get the hand of reading .txt files it's not even gonna be used so I'm not going to encrypt the passwords or anything.

Comment: What is not happening?

Comment: @Tirath, I'm getting a bunch of errors the main being java.util.NoSuchElementException. If you want the full error report I'd be happy to link one.

Comment: Sure. Please do that.

Comment: @Tirath, Here ya go. http://tny.cz/3087592b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - modify the `while` loop to `break` at some point. So, let say once you are done reading all the values `break` it. Something like

```
while(reader.hasNext()){
    website = reader.next();
    username = reader.next();
    password = reader.next();
    break;
} 
//similarly, you can modify the above code 
//if you can read all the inputs in one line
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] lineArray = reader.nextLine().split("specifyDelimeterHere");
    website = lineArray[0];
    username = lineArray[1];
    password = lineArray[2];
    break;
}
```

Now, **Why** the `NoSuchElementException`.

Honestly, this is a guess. You are most probably getting it because you are not breaking out of the `while` and/ or `closing` the scanner instance. Here the loop is expecting more input but the resource is getting closed. Use `close()` defined in `Scanner` class to close `reader` after the `while` loop.

Let me know in the comments if this helps or not.

Comment: I'm getting the "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" error on lineArray[1]. And shouldn't the `String lineArray` be `String[] lineArray` ?

Comment: If you are using the modification proposed then make sure you are passing all the values in required values in one line separated by the `delimeter` other add a check for proper values.

Comment: I would suggest, first try to make it work with what you already have. And, if you using file to read line then make sure in the file you have all three values in one row.

Comment: Managed to get it up and working. :) Thank you so much!